# Python Network/cidr Calculations

Tags: python, networking, scripting, cidr

I am working on building an embedded network appliance (linux based) and have come across the need to dynamically build daemon conf files.  As such, I need to be able to do some network address calculations in the python code that will be building the conf files.  I am not a programmer so I'm fearful I wrote a module that will fail to function as I'd hoped once the appliance starts shipping.

Below is what I have so far, its really pieced together with what I could find on this site and Google.

Is there a better method to find the network address and cidr for a network interface? Converting the netmask to a bin str and counting the 1's seems pretty inelegant.

```
import socket
import fcntl
import struct

SIOCGIFNETMASK = 0x891b
SIOCGIFADDR = 0x8915

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

def _GetIfaceMask(iface):
    return struct.unpack('L', fcntl.ioctl(s, SIOCGIFNETMASK, struct.pack('256s', iface))[20:24])[0]

def _GetIfaceAddr(iface):
    return struct.unpack('L', fcntl.ioctl(s, SIOCGIFADDR, struct.pack('256s', iface[:15]))[20:24])[0]

def GetIfaceNet(iface):
    net_addr = _GetIfaceAddr(iface) & _GetIfaceMask(iface)
    return socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('L', net_addr))

def GetIfaceCidr(iface):
    bin_str = bin(_GetIfaceMask(iface))[2:]
    cidr = 0
    for c in bin_str:
        if c == '1':  cidr += 1
    return cidr
```

Thanks for any input, I really am somewhat lost on this.  If this isn't the place for this type of feedback, please let me know.

Comment: Have you tried `netaddr` or `ipaddr` modules?

Comment: Ah! I figured someone must have done this already- thanks @sebastian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may check iptools python module http://code.google.com/p/python-iptools/ it can convert from long to dotted ip format and vise versa.

Answer (score 4):

This can be solved using a Hamming weight algorithm. Stolen from [How to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/best-algorithm-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer) and translated into Python:

```
def number_of_set_bits(x):
    x -= (x >> 1) & 0x55555555
    x = ((x >> 2) & 0x33333333) + (x & 0x33333333)
    x = ((x >> 4) + x) & 0x0f0f0f0f
    x += x >> 8
    x += x >> 16
    return x & 0x0000003f
```

Another, more readable solution (but running in `O(log x)`):

```
def number_of_set_bits(x):
    n = 0
    while x:
        n += x & 1
        x = x >> 1
    return n
```

Comment: O(log(x)), I think; you're looping over the number of bits in x, not x itself.